# Is It possible to sync MySQL table to SharePoint list through SharePoint Business Connectivity Service?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, business-data-catalog

I want know is it possible to connect MySQL table to SharePoint list ?

This question is asked in an interview for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to connect MySQL with BDC using `ODBC driver`.

You can refer this [Integrating SharePoint with MySQL using Business Data Catalog](http://walisystems.com/articles/SPS/bdc/bdc4/sharepoint,%20bdc%20and%20mysql.htm)

Please let me know if it help you.

Thanks